# Best practice for new column on base table

Tags: acumatica

I have a customization package that has some new columns on several main tables and also several new tables.  The new tables are in sql scripts and work fine.  The new columns for existing tables are currently in sql scrips also.  I did this a couple years ago and I honestly do not remember how I ended up there.  I recently encountered a problem with the Carrier table in 2017R2.  Apparently, there were columns added to the base table and publishing my project removed them.  I removed the sql script and re-added the custom column through the DAC object and not it seems to work fine.  I thought I had read somewhere that it was best to convert it to a main sql script.

I have other columns that I have added to SOOrder and SOShipment.  I want to make sure I don't have this problem again so I want to confirm the correct method for customizing tables.

Comment: If you are adding a column directly to the base table it needs to start with "Usr" or it will be removed during updates. Otherwise if you create your own table then the changes are based on the changes to your sql table entries. No need to write any sql syntax in both cases. just use the customization project to build the xml entries for the customization project.

Comment: I understand that and my new custom fields do start with usr.  I just want to know if they can be added with Database scripts or if they must be done with Data Access changes which seem to translate to two project objects - a DAC and a Table object.  Is it best to use the DAC change or create a sql script?  What should the sql script look like to just add columns?

Comment: you should not need (and avoid) creating sql scripts to do anything with the database unless necessary (in or outside of a customization project). The project table entry is all you need to get your column in the table.